# Solving Maven dependency error in Netbeans

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, maven, struts2

Why am I receiving the following error? I am using netbeans and not sure which commend line should I use to re-run the maven and follow the error's instructions. I have found this as well but still not sure where the command line is [Link](http://blog.dawouds.com/2008/11/missing-indirectly-referenced-artifact.html)

I have downloaded the following [Code](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hibernate-integration-example/) and tried to run it but it runs into following error

```
Failed to execute goal on project Struts2Example: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mkyong.common:Struts2Example:war:com.mkyong.common: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B, javax.security:jacc:jar:1.0: Failure to find javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular version of the jta.jar doesn't exist in the maven repository anymore.  Try changing the version to 1.1 and rebuilding.

Although, neither is that version of jacc.  So might still have problems.